# How Can I change ConstraintLayout verticalBias according to viewState value

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-constraintlayout

I have BindingAdapter like;

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("setVerticalBias")
fun ConstraintLayout.setVerticalBias(value: Float?) {
    val cs = ConstraintSet()
    cs.setVerticalBias(R.id.llResultContent, value ?: 0.1f)
    cs.applyTo(this)
}
```

And I have condition in my viewState which is manage float value like;

```
val constraintBias: Float
    get() {
        return if (hasSecondaryActions) {
            0.1f
        } else {
            0.8f
        }
    }
```

Then I used that with my binding adapter like;

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llResultContent"
        setVerticalBias="@{viewState.constraintBias}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

So I'm getting this error

***"Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.LinearLayout setVerticalBias> that accepts parameter type 'float'
If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
Open File"***

What is the problem here I can't find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setVerticalBias` is set on the *LinearLayout* not the *ConstraintLayout* even though the bias is used by the *ConstraintLayout*. Change your binding adapter to the following:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("setVerticalBias")
fun LinearLayout.setVerticalBias(value: Float?) {
    val constraintLayout = (this.parent as ConstraintLayout)
    val cs = ConstraintSet()
    cs.clone(constraintLayout)
    cs.setVerticalBias(R.id.llResultContent, value ?: 0.1f)
    cs.applyTo(constraintLayout)
}
```

or, more generally:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("setVerticalBias")
fun LinearLayout.setVerticalBias(value: Float?) {
    val constraintLayout = (this.parent as ConstraintLayout)
    val cs = ConstraintSet()
    cs.clone(constraintLayout)
    cs.setVerticalBias(this.id, value ?: 0.1f)
    cs.applyTo(constraintLayout)
}
```

Comment: It works with that way thanks, at the beginning I dont know why but I thought it was constraintlayout attribute :)

Comment: @EmreTekin It is a _ConstraintLayout_ attribute (_ConstraintLayout_ makes use of it), but it is defined with _ConstraintLayout_ children such as your _LinearLayout_.